# I am trying to match based on a dynamic cell reference with the match function

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

=MATCH(B$4,CONCATENATE("'",A5,"'!$E:$E"),0)

The above formula result is #VALUE!

Cell A5 has the value Sheet1, however, after testing this will change to a date e.g. 01-Jul-14

What am I doing wrong?

I am going to use it as part of a to build up a data table from daily sheets e.g. 
INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",A5,"'!",CONCATENATE("E",**MATCH(B$4,Sheet1!$E:$E,0)**)))

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use `INDIRECT` in your first formula. 
The second argument to `MATCH` needs to be an array, and you are passing it a string. 
Change it to

```
=MATCH(B$4, INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'", A5, "'!$E:$E")), 0)
```

Secondly, in the second formula,
you are calling `CONCATENATE` and passing its return value to another `CONCATENATE`. 
That’s quite unnecessary (i.e., unnecessarily complicated).
You can change

```
CONCATENATE("'", A5, "'!", CONCATENATE("E", MATCH(B$4,Sheet1!$E:$E,0)))
```

to

```
CONCATENATE("'", A5, "'!", "E", MATCH(B$4,Sheet1!$E:$E,0))
```

Also, Excel uses `&` as a concatenate operator, so you can replace the above with

```
"'" & A5 & "'!" & "E" & MATCH(B$4,Sheet1!$E:$E,0)
```

I find that to be easier to read, but that’s a matter of opinion.